# Сортировка массива на PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Всем привет.

Имеется массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [count] => 4
            [month] => May 2021
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [count] => 0
            [month] => April 2021
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [count] => 0
            [month] => March 2021
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [count] => 0
            [month] => February 2021
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [count] => 0
            [month] => January 2021
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [count] => 0
            [month] => December 2020
        )

)
```

Вопрос: как его отсортировать в обратном порядке? А также как перевести месяца на русский язык?

Answer (score 0):

Сортировку сделал так:

```
function sorta($a, $b) {
            if ($a['month'] > $b['month'])
                return 1;
        }

        usort($month, 'sorta');
```

А названия месяцев перевел так (в данном случае мне нужно было для smarty):

```
function smarty_modifier_month($text) {
    $trans = array("January" => "Январь",
        "February" => "Февраль",
        "March" => "Март",
        "April" => "Апрель",
        "May" => "Май",
        "June" => "Июнь",
        "July" => "Июль",
        "August" => "Август",
        "September" => "Сентябрь",
        "October" => "Октябрь",
        "November" => "Ноябрь",
        "December" => "Декабрь");

    return strtr($text, $trans);
}
```